# Splitting OpenEXR into different exposure images

Tags: image-processing, openexr

I'm trying to use this [dataset](http://rit-mcsl.org/fairchild//HDRPS/HDRthumbs.html) to do [Exposure Meging (Fusion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_fusion) in Python. Each image in the dataset has an [OpenEXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR) file that can be downloaded (i don't have much experience with this file format).

I want to extract different samples (jpg or png) from the OpenEXR file with different exposures .

I managed to do that in [Darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) :

- Open the OpenEXR file (image)
- Change the Exposure
- Save as jpg
- redo for each exposure value (-3EV, -2EV, -1EV, 0EV, 1EV, 2EV, 3EV).

The problem : I have 100 images and i want to automate this process. any idea on how to do that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since each increment of EV (*"Exposure Value"*) corresponds to doubling the exposure, and `EXR` files are in linear light (not gamma-encoded), you would expect that you can double the pixel values in an `EXR` file to add 1EV and halve them to do -1EV...

So, I downloaded the `Luxo` EXR file from [here](http://www.cis.rit.edu/fairchild/HDRPS/EXRs/LuxoDoubleChecker.exr). Then I went into Photoshop and clicked:

```
Image -> Mode -> 8-bits/channel
```

and selected `Method` = `Exposure and Gamma` and set `exposure=+1` and saved the resulting file as a `JPEG` with `+1` in its name. I repeated that for EV-3, EV-2, EV+0, EV+1, EV+2, EV+3.

[image]

I then looked at the resulting files with **ImageMagick** using commands like the following in the Terminal to examine the mean value of the combined RGB image:

```
magick identify -verbose image-EV+2.jpg
```

I then went about producing those same mean values, and found that the following works:

```
# To increase 1 EV
magick input.exr -evaluate multiply 2 result.jpg

# To increase 2 EV
magick input.exr -evaluate multiply 4 result.jpg

# To increase 3 EV
magick input.exr -evaluate multiply 8 result.jpg
```

And so on...

---

So, I wrote a `bash` script to do that as follows, which you could save in your HOME directory as `adjust.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Default file, if none specified
file=${1:-/Users/mark/Desktop/LuxoDoubleChecker.exr}

# Default EV of +1, if none specified
EV=${2:-1}

# Strip extension
base="${file%.*}"

# Apply given EV to file and save with new name
new="${base}EV${EV}.jpg"
echo "Applying EV $EV to $file, saving as $new"
magick "$file" -evaluate multiply $(bc -l <<< "2^$EV") "$new"
```

Then, just necessary once, make it executable:

```
chmod +x $HOME/adjust.sh
```

And then you run it like this to add +3EV to `SomeImage.exr`:

```
~/adjust.sh SomeImage.exr 3
```

**Sample Output**

```
Applying EV 3 to SomeImage.exr, saving as SomeImageEV3.jpg
```

---

Alternatively, if you save this script as `allEVs.sh`, it will load the specified image just once and generate all 7 exposures in one go without re-reading the input EXR file 7 times:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Default file, if none specified
file=${1:-/Users/mark/Desktop/LuxoDoubleChecker.exr}

# Strip extension to get base without extension
base="${file%.*}"

magick "$file" \
    \( +clone -evaluate multiply 0.125 -write "${base}EV-3.jpg" +delete \)  \
    \( +clone -evaluate multiply 0.25  -write "${base}EV-2.jpg" +delete \)  \
    \( +clone -evaluate multiply 0.5   -write "${base}EV-1.jpg" +delete \)  \
    \( +clone -evaluate multiply 1     -write "${base}EV-0.jpg" +delete \)  \
    \( +clone -evaluate multiply 2     -write "${base}EV+1.jpg" +delete \)  \
    \( +clone -evaluate multiply 4     -write "${base}EV+2.jpg" +delete \)  \
              -evaluate multiply 8     "${base}EV+3.jpg"
```

[image]

Please check carefully that this works correctly for you before basing a lifetime's analysis on it...

**Keywords**: Image processing, HDR, High Dynamic Range, EXR, EV, Exposure Value, f-stop, stop, stops, exposure, increase, decrease, tone map, ImageMagick.

Comment: you're too good for this world ... THANK YOU SO MUCH .. you're a life saver .. i have only checked 2 conversition and they seem pretty good, there is only one issue. these are from the conversion of AhwahneeGreatLounge : https://imgur.com/a/5ceIJHv ...