# Get EXR image luminance

Tags: image-processing, colors, hdr, luminance, exposure

As far as i know, I think to get an image.exr luminance we have to render the image in different exposure and gather them into one ?

Here is my image made in Adobe which have different luminance from 0(left) to 10 (right) in exr extension.
[exr_to_png_forViewingPurpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4A1u.png)

**FIRST TEST :**

so I tried ImageMagick with this command line from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740992/splitting-openexr-into-different-exposure-images):

```
magick .\img.exr -evaluate multiply 2 img1EV.png
```

So I did the same for +-2EV, and +-3EV but the negatif EV give me an empty image.

**SECOND TEST :**

I saw on this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46825) that use different exposure as 0.1, 0.2, 0.4 etc...
I did the same with a sofware to get the same value of exposure as him.

Next, I implemented a program in py to get the right luminance from a png (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56678483/17659599)).

In the end with the first test, I have the same result for each image that have different exposure.
For the second test, I do have different image but I don't know what to do with them after that.
I don't know if it's the right way to do it, hope someone knows.

[FirstTest Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qA6J.png)
[SecondTest Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmzwS.png)

Comment: Perhaps just convert your image with -colorspace LAB and separate the 0 (the first or L, luminance) channel. `magick image.exr -colorspace LAB -channel 0 -separate luminance.png`